# Hibernate component versus many-to-one with unique

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a question about using component versus many-to-one with unique.

```
class Student
{
    String name
    Address addr
}

class Address
{
    String street;
    String city;
}
```

If I need to save the Student in database. I can either use component to put it in a table. Or I can use many-to-one and unique=true to put them into 2 tables.

So, in terms of design, which way is better? Can you discuss when should we use component and when should we use many-to-one with unique=true?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

as per my knowledge here we require many to one relationship because one at one address multiple student live so if we use unique key of address then we get normalize data by avoiding redundancy here.